# Getting list of fields available for a specific Adwords Report through Google Adwords API

Tags: java, google-ads-api

Is there any way that I can get the list of all the fields available for a specific report using Google Adwords API. I am using Adwords API version 201605.

For example,

```
    selector.getFields().addAll(Lists.newArrayList("CampaignId",
    "AdGroupId",
    "Id",
    "AdNetworkType2",
    "CriteriaType",
    "Criteria",
    "FinalUrls",
    "Impressions",
    "Clicks",
    "Cost"));
```

This is how I am selecting what fields I need in the report. But there are more than 90 fields that are available for each report. I need to select all of the fields in my case. So, Is there any thing in adwords api similar to below code:

```
    selector.getFields().addAll(Report.getFields("ReportType")));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this later, as of at least (maybe earlier versions as well) v201708 you can do the following.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/reporting#get-report-fields

```
public class GetReportFields {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential.
    Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
        .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
        .fromFile()
        .build()
        .generateCredential();

    // Construct an AdWordsSession.
    AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder()
        .fromFile()
        .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
        .build();

    AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices = AdWordsServices.getInstance();

    runExample(adWordsServices, session);
  }

  public static void runExample(
      AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices, AdWordsSession session) throws Exception {
    // Get the ReportDefinitionService.
    ReportDefinitionServiceInterface reportDefinitionService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, ReportDefinitionServiceInterface.class);

    // Get report fields.
    ReportDefinitionField[] reportDefinitionFields =
        reportDefinitionService
            .getReportFields(ReportDefinitionReportType.KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);

    // Display report fields.
    System.out.println("Available fields for report:");

    for (ReportDefinitionField reportDefinitionField : reportDefinitionFields) {
      System.out.printf("\t %s(%s) := [", reportDefinitionField.getFieldName(),
          reportDefinitionField.getFieldType());
      if (reportDefinitionField.getEnumValues() != null) {
        for (String enumValue : reportDefinitionField.getEnumValues()) {
          System.out.printf("%s, ", enumValue);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("]");
    }
  }
}
```